# OData -Only return record where all criteria is met from URL query

Tags: c#, odata

I'm learning OData v8, using Entity Framework Core and .NET 6.

Im playing about with Any()...

We Have:

```
public class car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Picture> Pictures{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Colour> Colours{ get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string url{ get; set; }
    public bool showImage { get; set; }
    public Car Car{ get; set; }
}

public class Colour
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColourName { get; set; }
    public string RGBValue{ get; set; }
    public Car Car{ get; set; }
}
         
[AllowAnonymous]
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet("Get")]
public ActionResult<IQueryable<Car>> Get()
{
   var cars = _context.car.AsQueryable();
   return Ok(cars);
}
```

So for exmaple if I call:

```
https://localhost:7221/api/Cars/Get?$filter=Pictures/any() and Colours/any()&$expand=Pictures($select=url;$filter=showImage eq true)&$expand=Colours($select=ColourName;$filter=RGBValue eq '123')&$select=Name
```

I am using 2 Anys() to apply to my search to return if:
Any() on Pictures, (will return if collection is populated)
Expand, (show if)
using filter, if show image is true,
then select URL

filter=Pictures/any() &$expand=Pictures($select=url;$filter=showImage eq true)

Likewise for colour:
Any() on colours
Expand,
filter where RGBValue = 123.
then select COlourName
&$expand=Colours($select=ColourName;$filter=RGBValue eq '123')

and then return car name in search

This is all good and works if both collections have values Pictures & Colours.

**However the problem arises for exmaple if colours query requirments is met, but pictures is not,
it will still return the car object, showing empty pictures[]**

**in the below exmaple only the first record should be shown**

eg:

```
*[
    {
        "Pictures": [
        {
        "url": "www.images.com/123"
            }
    ],
        "Colours": [
            {
                "ColourName": "Green"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Car 1 Name"
    },
    {
        "Pictures": [],
        "New_Price": [
            {
                "ColourName": "Blue"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Car 2 Name"
    }
]*
```

so esentially something like a Any() && Any()

Can anyone see where I am going wrong please? Thank you for any response

Comment: Tried your code in a webapi project Core 3.0, OData.Core 7.20.0 and worked fine. It returns only the first record but my url looks like `https://localhost:44359/odata/cars?$filter=Pictures/any() and Colours/any()&$expand=Pictures($select=url;$filter=showImage eq true)&$expand=Colours($select=ColourName;$filter=RGBValue eq '123')&$select=Name` Sorry my Visual Studio doesn't support .Net 6, can't reproduce the issue here.

Comment: In Startup class, my `ConfigureServices` method contains `modelBuilder.EntityType<Colour>(); modelBuilder.EntityType<Picture>(); modelBuilder.EntitySet<Car>("Cars"); services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents("odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()));` My cars controller inherits from odata controller: `public class CarsController : ODataController`

Comment: Hi derloopkat, thanks for the reply. Ok in new version of odata I dont think that all is needed all I have in program.cs is builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles).AddOData(options => options.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().SetMaxTop(null));

Comment: also didnt havemodelBuilder.EntityType<Colour>(); modelBuilder.EntityType<Picture>(); modelBuilder.EntitySet<Car>("Cars"); and controller only has: public class CarsController: Controller   but the query is working thus far so I dont think these are the issues